# I feel none of the work I do is what my manager wants. Is this grounds enough to quit?

Tags: work-environment, resignation, quitting

I'm working as a print media designer on a contract.

Currently, 90% of the work I do is rejected. This is higher than any other job I've had. I've asked for clarification a few times but don't get anything useful back.

Its been 3 months and I'm beginning to really dread going into work each day. I don't feel like I'm being productive and it's really crushing my moral to be rejected so many times.

Is it better to just admit I don't 'click' with the company professionally and move on?

Comment: Sorry, but only _you_ can decide if you are unhappy enough to quit.  We can't make that determination for you as everyone has different thresholds.  Any answers can only be opinion based and therefore the question is off topic.

Comment: Whats different about the 10% that gets accepted?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what is going on here. On what grounds are your work getting "rejected?" It's hard to imagine you are asked to do something, then they just promptly destroy it. Are these works something you thought of? Or are you going to a review where they make suggestions that make you think they are rejections?

Comment: @Dan because it's design the results of the work is subjective. I'll get a task like 'design the cover of this pamphlet' and I'll use my skills and experience to do just that. I'll submit the work but they'll just say that it's 'not quite what we're  after' with no other feedback and I'll start again. Sure, you've got to expect some rejection in this line of work but the frequency here is way to high and the feedback is very very little. If it were a freelance gig I would have dropped the client..

Comment: Re:"Design the cover of this pamphlet"/"With no other feedback and I'll start again" - Do you expect to do better than 90% rejection with this approach? I sure wouldn't. It is like saying to a programmer - Design a website for company xyz and the programmer going off in a bubble and creating whatever comes to mind. Do you think anybody is going to be happy with that website more than 10% of the time? Seems like you need to learn to ask questions that give you the kind of answers you need in order to properly do your job. That's on you, not your company or customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they haven't threatened to fire you.... maybe they actually expect 90% of the work to be "good try, not what we were looking for, try something else."

If so then you need to work on finding ways to test experiments with them before you have invested so much of your own emotions and time ("fail fast" design) -- or work with them to try to help them develop a vocabulary for explaining their goals and reactions -- or, more likely, both of these and other tricks.

Talk to more experienced pros in your specialty about finding ways to better manage the customer.

Otherwise moving to another job might not solve the problem.